# GRUB is searching his config file on an USB device, not on his hd0 partition

Tags: boot, grub2

I am facing a problem with GRUB.

I want to execute a command when I boot, but this command acts on an USB ultrawide band device. The problem is that GRUB doesn't boot and I faced the "Minimal BASH-like" screen, as if it wants to boot on the USB device and not with the config file of GRUB.
I think a possible cause could be that it boot on hd0 but when I plug the USB device in, it takes the hd0 partition, and the config file is ignored.

Anyone knows what to change in the config file grub.cfg or somewhere else to avoid the crash during the boot and to execute my command ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Over the years most of my systems also promote a flash drive to hd0. But your configfile if UEFI should be using UUID, so not an issue. BIOS should also be using UUIDs. UEFI or BIOS install? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: BIOS installed. 
Here is the pastebin : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5sxjHXT36w/

Comment: You have mixed UEFI & BIOS as you have ESP with boot files for UEFI and and grub in MBR for BIOS boot. Only one or the other will work. Report did not show fstab, to know which way you last installed. But for UEFI boot to work you need esp,boot flags on p1 with gparted from live installer. You also have MBR partitions which with Ubuntu will work, but gpt partitions are highly recommended with UEFI. You also can use gpt with BIOS boot, but then need a tiny 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag.